# Cannot create a semaphore as standard user on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, synchronization, semaphore

I don't know if this is by design or not, but I cannot seem to create a new Semaphore on Windows 7 as a Standard User, or a Power User for that matter.

```
SemaphoreSecurity semSec = new SemaphoreSecurity(); 

// have also tried "Power Users", "Everyone", etc. 
SemaphoreAccessRule rule = new SemaphoreAccessRule("Users", SemaphoreRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);   

semSec.AddAccessRule(rule);

bool createdNew = false;

// throws exception 
sem = new Semaphore(1, 1, SEMAPHORE_ID, out createdNew, semSec);  

return true;
```

I am receiving an `UnauthorizedAccessException` with the message "Access to the port is denied."

Is this possible?

Comment: Out of all of those, only mutex works inter-process, I believe. And mutex doesn't signal the way I need --  any thread can call release() on a semaphore, whereas with mutex, only the thread that obtained the lock can release it, and there's no counting mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and trying things out I finally solved this,

The key is to prepend "Global\" to the semaphore name, ie,

```
    const string NAME = "Global\\MySemaphore";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MSDN documentation on that topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz356skf.aspx), it seems that the solution is to set the security level for the Semaphore creation.

Here is a source code excerpt from the given link:

```
// The value of this variable is set by the semaphore 
// constructor. It is true if the named system semaphore was 
// created, and false if the named semaphore already existed. 
// 
bool semaphoreWasCreated;

// Create an access control list (ACL) that denies the 
// current user the right to enter or release the  
// semaphore, but allows the right to read and change 
// security information for the semaphore. 
// 
string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" 
    + Environment.UserName;
SemaphoreSecurity semSec = new SemaphoreSecurity();

SemaphoreAccessRule rule = new SemaphoreAccessRule(
    user, 
    SemaphoreRights.Synchronize | SemaphoreRights.Modify, 
    AccessControlType.Deny);
semSec.AddAccessRule(rule);

rule = new SemaphoreAccessRule(
    user, 
    SemaphoreRights.ReadPermissions | SemaphoreRights.ChangePermissions,
    AccessControlType.Allow);
semSec.AddAccessRule(rule);

// Create a Semaphore object that represents the system 
// semaphore named by the constant 'semaphoreName', with 
// maximum count three, initial count three, and the 
// specified security access. The Boolean value that  
// indicates creation of the underlying system object is 
// placed in semaphoreWasCreated. 
//
sem = new Semaphore(3, 3, semaphoreName, 
    out semaphoreWasCreated, semSec);

// If the named system semaphore was created, it can be 
// used by the current instance of this program, even  
// though the current user is denied access. The current 
// program enters the semaphore. Otherwise, exit the 
// program. 
//  
if (semaphoreWasCreated)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Created the semaphore.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to create the semaphore.");
    return;
}
```

Hope this helps!