# how to get line number in async await C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I am investigating an error when using async/await. However, it displays as below and does not show the line number.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the port is denied. 
at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str) 
at System.Threading.Semaphore..ctor(Int32 initialCount, Int32 maximumCount, String name) 
at StorageServiceIntegration.Managers.StorageServiceManager.d__41.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
at StorageServiceIntegration.Managers.StorageServiceManager.d__33.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
at StorageServiceIntegration.Managers.StorageServiceManager.d__32.MoveNext()
```

How to show the line number and where the code failed? I am using .Net 4.6.1

Comment: Your exception is thrown because the user account under which you are running the application is not allowed to create a semaphore. This issue is similar to [Cannot create a semaphore as standard user on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530886/cannot-create-a-semaphore-as-standard-user-on-windows-7).

Comment: not in my case, it can create semaphore because it does thing after the semaphore.WaitOne() and log to the database.

Comment: `async` has nothing to do with the call stack returned by an exception. You need to have debug symbols and/or the source code for a library in order to see line numbers in a call stack

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you build in Debug mode in Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually, it's the debug symbols for the libraries that are necessary. If StorageServiceIntegration is an external dll without any debug symbols, compiling in Debug mode won't generate line numbers